# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState when replacing any fragment from activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to replace fragment on listeview setOnItemClickListener but getting below crashing issue:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65599, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.demo/com.demo.ui.SipHome}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4323)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4366)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1527)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1545)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:654)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:621)
at com.demo.eu.siacs.conversations.ui.StartConversationActivity.openConversationFromConversationList(StartConversationActivity.java:3436)
at com.demo.eu.siacs.conversations.ui.StartConversationActivity.onActivityResult(StartConversationActivity.java:1743)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:165)
at paycalldailer.paycall.co.il.ui.SipHome.onActivityResult(SipHome.java:1877)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4319)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4366) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Here I am opening one activity onclick of floating button and below is the code for that :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PaycallContacts.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CREATE_CHAT);
```

Then On, onActivityResult() I am trying to replace fragment like :

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CREATE_CHAT) {

Fragment currentFragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameChat);
        if (currentFragment instanceof ConversationFragment && getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
            return;
        }

if(!getActivity().isFinishing()) {
            mConversationFragment = new ConversationFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frameChat, mConversationFragment, "conversation");
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            transaction.commit();
        }

        //switchToConversation(conversation);
        openConversation();

        getChildFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(addOnBackStackChangedListener);

}
```

Is there any one have idea How can I resolve that crashing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()` may work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @liubaoyua
Your answer resolve my problem but transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss() not work alone 
First I override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) method and remove super() method calling from there and then commiteAllowingStateLoss() work.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```